# Insert page numbers across worksheets

Tags: excel

How do I insert sequential page numbering in a simple format of 1 2 3 4 across several worksheets in 1 workbook?

Comment: Share what you already tried.

Comment: Do you want one "page number" for each worksheet, or one number for each page in the workbook? (one worksheet can have multiple pages)

Answer (score 1):

Select all sheets first (right click on a sheet tab)

Print

Ungroup the sheets